# Input conditions to execute coordinator action using Oozie

Tags: hadoop, hdfs, bigdata, oozie

I'm new in oozie. I want to configure my coordinator to be executed only if Four files are presented in my Input folder. I did some searches on the oozie documentation and I found I can use Input-event with datasets.

```
  <datasets>
    <dataset name="dinput" frequency="${coord:days(1)}"
             initial-instance="${start_date}" timezone="UTC">
      <uri-template>myInputFolder</uri-template>
      <done-flag></done-flag>
    </dataset>
  </datasets>
  <input-events>
    <data-in name="input" dataset="dinput">
      <instance>${coord:current(0)}</instance>
    </data-in>
  </input-events>
```

Can someOne please guide me to do this.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The intention of Oozie's `<dataset>` and `<input-events>` tags is to handle the common case when data is coming in at a specific interval and lands in a date-partitioned directory structure. That is where Oozie works the best.

If this doesn't fit your use case, my suggestion would be to write some code to check for your files and run it in an Oozie action using the shell or java action type. I think that this action could send a failure code to Oozie to halt the workflow if your files don't exist, and this action would precede the real logic of your workflow.

Comment: Thanks for your reply. I'm writing a script to count file in an input directory in HDFS. How can get the output of this script in a workflow ssh action. I need to call sending mail action if there is less than four files in my input directory... Can you please guide me to do this.

Comment: You should look up the `<capture-output>` element. Using this you can capture a value from your ssh action and use it with Oozie expression language in your subsequent email action.

Comment: If you're going to be using Oozie a lot, I recommend you find the book Apache Oozie by Mohammad Kamrul Islam and Aravind Srinivasan published by O’Reilly Media.